# Data in multiple sheets with empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

Hello i have workbook with multiple sheets inside. I created macro that delete two columns of data(without headers) in those sheets. I used `.Find` to look for the headers `MEASURED VALUE` so macro will delete only data below those found headers. This is my code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer



For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Debug.Print ws.Name

 r = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(what:="MEASURED VALUE", lookat:=xlWhole).Row
 c = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Find(what:="MEASURED VALUE", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

Range(ws.Cells(2, c), ws.Cells(r, c).End(xlDown)).ClearContents

Next ws

End Sub
```

This code works it is deleting data in found columns and in every sheets. But there is a possibility that some rows will be empty. My question is how do i make code delete all the data not just data that are above the empty row. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if not found?

Comment: @Qharr Hello again Qharr :) Don't worry i thought about that and i know how to deal with it at least i think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range(ws.Cells(2, c), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
```

instead of this:

```
Range(ws.Cells(2, c), ws.Cells(r, c).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
```

Your approach could be visualised like this:

> Look all the way down the column until first blank cell.

My approach, on the other hand, is like:

> Go to the bottom of a column (achieved using `ws.Rows.Count`) and go up until first non-blank cell.

Comment: do i even need the  `r` variable in this problem?

Comment: @TooMachoBA Apparently not :)